# Have to find if some window name has some string on it with python

Tags: python, winapi, window

First of all, I get the name of the current window

```
win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
```

k, no problem with that...

But now, how can I make an if with the result for having an specific string on it...

For example, the result gave me

```
C:/Python26/
```

How can I make an True of False for the result containing the word, 'python' ?

I'm trying with re.search, but I'm not being able to make it do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python` is not the same as `Python`. You probably need to pass `re.IGNORECASE` to enable case-insensitive matching. Example:

```
title = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
if re.search(title, "python", re.IGNORECASE):
    print "Found it!"
```

However, if you don't need the power of regexes, it is simpler and faster to do a simple string search:

```
if title.lower().find("python") >= 0:
```

Comment: Or `if "python" in title.lower(): ...`